# Can't access variable within class instance

Tags: php, class, laravel

I can't seem to access $module within the Breadcrumbs instance. How can I access it?

```
$modules = Module::all();

foreach ($modules as $module)
{
    Breadcrumbs::register($module->name, function($b)
    {
        $b->parent('modules');
        $b->push($module->display_name, url('/module/' . $module->name));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variable scope issue. To be able to access local variables inside a closure you have to inject them with `use(...)`

```
Breadcrumbs::register($module->name, function($b) use ($module)
{
    $b->parent('modules');
    $b->push($module->display_name, url('/module/' . $module->name));
});
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16959577/1903366) provides a very good explanation of the whole topic

Answer (score 0):

```
$modules = Module::all();

foreach ($modules as $module)
{
    Breadcrumbs::register($module->name, function($b) use ($module)
    {
        $b->parent('modules');
        $b->push($module->display_name, url('/module/' . $module->name));
    });
}
```

Hence the [use](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) keyword.